# Use incompatible versions of JiBX Runtime

Tags: java, runtime, jibx

I want to use 2 libraries that have been built with different and incompatible versions of JiBX.

- Lib #1 runs with JiBX Runtime 1.0.1
- Lib #2 runs with JiBX Runtime 1.2.6

The current version number is coded in the interface : **org.jibx.runtime.IBindingFactory#CURRENT_VERSION_NUMBER** .

When calling **org.jibx.runtime.BindingDirectory#getFactory()**, there's a compatibility test.
If the generated class and the runtime are incompatible, we got an exception like this :

> Caused by: org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: Binding information for
>   class Xxxx must be
>   regenerated with current binding compiler     at
>   org.jibx.runtime.BindingDirectory.getFactoryFromName(Unknown Source)
>     at org.jibx.runtime.BindingDirectory.getFactory(Unknown Source)

EDIT - 29/07/2015
Another possible exception :

> Caused by: org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: Binding information for
>   class
>   Yyyyy must
>   be recompiled with current binding compiler (compiled with jibx_1_0_1,
>   runtime is jibx_1_2_5_SNAPSHOT)   at
>   org.jibx.runtime.BindingDirectory.getFactoryFromName(BindingDirectory.java:125)
>     at
>   org.jibx.runtime.BindingDirectory.getFactory(BindingDirectory.java:178)
>     at
>   org.jibx.runtime.BindingDirectory.getFactory(BindingDirectory.java:197)

**Is it possible to make it work ?**

---

I've looked at the doc about JiBX [Runtime](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/runtime.html) but didn't found anything.

[JiBX Runtime](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.jibx%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jibx-run%22) on Maven Central Repo.